# How to input vlookup formula on visible cells with reference from another workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a workbook that will be filtered, and I need to input a vlookup formula on the visible cells in column "AA". However, the table array is on another workbook. I'm aware of how to do it on excel, but not how to code it. Is it possible to do so with VBA? Is there also a better way to do this besides vlookup?

- Filename of reference file = `"TestCases.xlsm"`
- Filename of output file = `"Actual.xlsx"`

  ```
  Range("AA2:AA" & lastrow).Formula = "=vlookup(A10, '[TestCases.xlsm]tc'!$B$3:$M$8, 1,0)"
  ```

This is what I'd key into a cell. It doesn't work as I wouldn't know the row number of the first visible cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is your goal to actually have formulas, or is your goal to have the right values?

Comment: You have to Enter that in a VB Editor Window, not in a Cell. And for the Visible cells you can use `Range("AA2:AA" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: @Mikku, it works if the first visible filtered cell is 10, otherwise it doesn't, any idea how to overcome that?